# ssh tunnel VNC server connection closed unexpectedly

Tags: ssh, remote-access, ssh-tunnel, vnc

I have to tunnel the VNC server(tightvnc-server) running on my local machine to a remote server, so at remote server  can access my local machine without port forwarding on router(at local machine network).

Right now I am using the following command

```
      ssh -R 5950:localhost:5900 user@remote.ddns.net
```

Where  `5900`  the vnc server port on my local machine. And I have to access the machine from remote server using the command localhost:5950. And when I try to connect using vnc viewer I am getting the error `connection closed unexpectedly`. Normally if no connection exist I was getting connection refused error. But here something is missing in tunneling. Can any please tell me what could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the remote desktop, running:

`sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart \ -activate -configure -access -on \ -restart -agent -privs -all`

Then you can connected using VNC Viewer